# Cannot Start Unicorn

Tags: ruby, unicorn

I wanted to restart Unicorn to check out some edits i did locally on some Views.

I was able to stop Unicorn. For some reason it will not restart.

here is the Error it is giving me:

```
Executing /etc/rc.d/init.d/unicorn_loadmax start ..

/etc/rc.d/init.d/unicorn_loadmax: line 20: kill: (24317) - No such process
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

here is my unicorn Script

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Example init script, this can be used with nginx, too,
# since nginx and unicorn accept the same signals

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/loadmax/current
PID=/home/deployer/loadmax/shared/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd /home/deployer/loadmax/current && bundle exec /home/deployer/loadmax/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn -D -c /home/deployer/loadmax/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
        test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        su -c "$CMD" - $AS_USER
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
force-stop)
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
restart|reload)
        sig USR2 && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - $AS_USER
        ;;
upgrade)
        if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
        then
                n=$TIMEOUT
                while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
                do
                        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
                done
                echo

                if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
                then
                        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
                        exit 1
                fi
                exit 0
        fi
        echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - $AS_USER
        ;;
reopen-logs)
        sig USR1
        ;;
*)
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

LOG FILE:

```
I, [2014-03-24T15:25:07.830877 #13704]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

/home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /home/deployer/website/releases/20140111043133/app/models/document.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `safe_constantize'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /home/deployer/website/releases/20140111043133/app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/deployer/website/releases/20140111043133/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:4:in `require'
    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /home/deployer/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

document.rb

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :filename, :filesize, :filetype, :name, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  FILENAME_FORMAT = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/
  BAD_FILETYPE_FORMAT = /^Badfiletype$/
  MIME_HASH = { "doc" => "application/msword",
                "docx" => "application/msword",
                "dot" => "application/msword",
                "xml" => "application/xml",
                "pdf" => "application/pdf",
                "tif" => "image/tif",
                "txt" => "text/plain",
                "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                "xlsx" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
                "pptx" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
                "gif" => "image/gif",
                "png" => "image/png",
                "jpg" => "image/jpg",
                "jpeg" => "image/jpg",
                "ps" => "application/postscript",
                "rtf" => "application/rtf",
                "zip" => "application/zip" }

  validates_numericality_of :filesize, less_than: 50M
  validates_format_of :filename, with: FILENAME_FORMAT
  validates_format_of :filetype, without: BAD_FILETYPE_FORMAT
end
```

I DID change line 26 Yesterday...

changed 2048   to 50M

Comment: What's in your `document.rb`? around line 26...

Comment: which one there are a ton of document.rb files included with ruby.

Comment: yours: `/home/deployer/website/releases/20140111043133/app/models/document.rb`

Comment: i did change line 26 yesterday to increase the size of files uploaded

Comment: well that was it... thank you if you post an answer i will accept it... changed it back to original and unicorn started right up

Comment: I did post an answer... below...

Comment: Quick Question thou... when i changed the 2048 to 50M i was able to upload larger files.... now that i changed it back i cant upload the larger files... is it formatted wrong

Comment: you need `less_then` to be a number. I'm not sure what's the unit used for `filesize` (probably Kb?) if so - it should be 50*1024, which is 51200

Comment: well i will have to look into it more... but when i have it at 50M it allows me to use the document upload... but when i change it to anthing without the M it gives me a 405 Not ALLOWED error...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about, since when you had it at 50M _it didn't work_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script crashes on the following line:

```
test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
```

`$PID` is set in:

```
PID=/home/deployer/loadmax/shared/pids/unicorn.pid
```

and `test -s` checks that the file exists, and has a size larger than zero.

Try deleting this file, then running the script again.

---

As for line 26 - try removing the `M` - it is not a number... - simply put 50

Comment: did that and got Executing /etc/rc.d/init.d/unicorn_loadmax start ..
master failed to start, check stderr log for details

Comment: i added the log file above

Comment: added a suggestion for line 26

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs for exact error. However, a simple fix would be to kill the process and restart the unicorn.

```
ps aux | grep unicorn
```

Then, locate the master process in there.

```
kill <process-id>
```

Then, try start the server again.

Comment: root     28641  0.0  0.0   6376   680 pts/0    S+   14:55   0:00 grep unicorn

Comment: there is no processes runing for unicorn... i have webmin installed and can see all processes running...

Comment: Found and Added log file to the post